# Take Photo and Show it on Activity Screen

Tags: android

I made an Activity that take a picture. Then I want to show that picture on activity background.

Here is my code:

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     ...
     new java.util.Timer().schedule(
            new java.util.TimerTask() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    preview.camera.takePicture(shutterCallback, rawCallback, jpegCallback);
                }
            },
            1000
    );
    ImageView image = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    image.getLayoutParams().width = 100;
    image.getLayoutParams().height = 100;
    image.setAdjustViewBounds(true);
    image.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/DCIM/photo.jpeg"));
}
```

This code take the picture but it doesn't show the picture taken on activity background. I don't know how to make it work. Thanks.

Comment: setImageBitmap inside run() method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add this code in your `jpegCallback` method.

```
image.getLayoutParams().width = 100;
    image.getLayoutParams().height = 100;
    image.setAdjustViewBounds(true);
    image.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/DCIM/photo.jpeg"))
```